# tf.contrib.summary.generic or tf.summary.text in eager mode

Tags: tensorflow

It looks like only tf.contrib.summary.scalar is supported when using eager mode. Is there a workaround to use tf.contrib.summary.generic or tf.summary.text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are mistaken. **All** the summary methods in `tf.contrib.summary` are supported for both eager execution and graph construction. For example, something like this seems to work:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

with tf.contrib.summary.create_file_writer('/tmp/logdir').as_default(), tf.contrib.summary.always_record_summaries():
  for step in range(3):
    tf.contrib.summary.generic("generic", tf.pow(10., step), step=step)
    tf.contrib.summary.histogram("histogram", tf.random_uniform([10]), step=step)
  tf.contrib.summary.flush()
```

With `tensorboard --logdir /tmp/logdir --inspect` you can see that 3 events each are written, and of course the histogram can be visualized in `tensorboard`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Generic does appear in the event I was only looking in tensorboard. Is/will there be a way to see 'generic' information in tensorboard? Will text be supported in eager mode?

Comment: I don't know about the `generic` visualization in TensorBoard, you might want to file a feature request for that. I don't see why `text` can't be support with eager execution, you might want to file a feature request for that as well :)