# How to write to TensorBoard in TensorFlow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm quite familiar in TensorFlow 1.x and I'm considering to switch to TensorFlow 2 for an upcoming project. I'm having some trouble understanding **how to write scalars to TensorBoard logs with eager execution**, using a [custom training loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough).

#### Problem description

In tf1 you would create some summary ops (one op for each thing you would want to store), which you would then merge into a single op, run that merged op inside a session and then write this to a file using a FileWriter object. Assuming `sess` is our `tf.Session()`, an example of how this worked can be seen below:

```py
# While defining our computation graph, define summary ops:
# ... some ops ...
tf.summary.scalar('scalar_1', scalar_1)
# ... some more ops ...
tf.summary.scalar('scalar_2', scalar_2)
# ... etc.

# Merge all these summaries into a single op:
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

# Define a FileWriter (i.e. an object that writes summaries to files):
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir, sess.graph)

# Inside the training loop run the op and write the results to a file:
for i in range(num_iters):
    summary, ... = sess.run([merged, ...], ...)
    writer.add_summary(summary, i)
```

The problem is that sessions don't exist anymore in tf2 and I would prefer not disabling eager execution to make this work. The [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard) is written for tf1 and all references I can find suggest using the Tensorboard keras callback. However, as far as I know, this only works if you train the model through `model.fit(...)` and not through a [custom training loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough).

#### What I've tried

- The tf1 version of `tf.summary` functions, outside of a session. Obviously any combination of these functions fails, as FileWriters, merge_ops, etc. don't even exist in tf2.
- [This medium post](https://medium.com/tensorflow/effective-tensorflow-2-0-best-practices-and-whats-changed-a0ca48767aff) states that there has been a "cleanup" in some tensorflow APIs including `tf.summary()`. They suggest using `from tensorflow.python.ops.summary_ops_v2`, which doesn't seem to work. This [implies](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/summary_ops_v2.py#L125) using a `record_summaries_every_n_global_steps`; more on this later.
- A series of other posts [1](https://medium.com/coinmonks/8-things-to-do-differently-in-tensorflows-eager-execution-mode-47cf429aa3ad), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49711324/tf-contrib-summary-generic-or-tf-summary-text-in-eager-mode), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257614/tensorflow-eager-and-tensorboard-graphs), suggest using the `tf.contrib.summary` and `tf.contrib.FileWriter`. However, `tf.contrib` [has been removed from the core TensorFlow repository and build process](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/pull/18).
- [A TensorFlow v2 showcase from the official repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tf2_showcase/mnist.py), which again uses the `tf.contrib` summaries along with the `record_summaries_every_n_global_steps` mentioned previously. I couldn't make this to work either (even without using the contrib library).

#### tl;dr

My questions are:

- Is there a way to properly use `tf.summary` in TensroFlow 2?
- If not, is there another way to write TensorBoard logs in TensorFlow 2, when using a custom training loop (not `model.fit()`)?

Comment: For adding 2 scalars in one plot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58181527/merging-2-plots-in-tensorboard-2-with-tensorflow-2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, there is a simpler and more elegant way to use summaries in TensorFlow v2.

First, create a file writer that stores the logs (e.g. in a directory named `log_dir`):

```py
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(log_dir)
```

Anywhere you want to write something to the log file (e.g. a scalar) use your good old `tf.summary.scalar` inside a context created by the writer. Suppose you want to store the value of `scalar_1` for step `i`:

```py
with writer.as_default():
    tf.summary.scalar('scalar_1', scalar_1, step=i)
```

You can open as many of these contexts as you like inside or outside of your training loop.

Example:

```py
# create the file writer object
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(log_dir)

for i, (x, y) in enumerate(train_set):

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_ = model(x)
        loss = loss_func(y, y_)

    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

    # write the loss value
    with writer.as_default():
        tf.summary.scalar('training loss', loss, step=i+1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I can't believe they don't have any documentation for this!

Comment: @mathtick one possible solution is to make two different subfolders (eg. 'training' and 'validation'). If you pass the parent folder to tensorboard you'll get a run for each subfolder on the same plot.

Comment: Why this doesn't work hen using graph execution with `@tf.function`?

Comment: The commands shown in the example should work fine in graph mode. Maybe something else in your graph is causing the issue. You could look at an example of this [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/migrate).